# How to fill a PDF form using JS/HTML/CSS/Node.js/PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, html, postgresql, pdf

I am currently in a BootCamp trying to work on a capstone project. I am in the AF Reserves and we use a site that you can enter information in and it is supposed to take that information and use it to populate a fillable PDF. Unfortunately, that feature doesn't actually work and I am wondering if this is something I can build using the CRUD stack I have learned of JS/CSS/HTML/Node.js/PostgreSQL and how to even approach doing it. Before I even begin working on the front in and the data capture I wanted to know if there is even a way to transfer the data I am collecting and transfer it to the fillable form.

If there are methods using other languages I would greatly appreciate the knowledge of how to do it in them. I want to improve the military process as it's a big function of my job and right now a redundant process of filling out all the information on our site and then manually having to fill out the pdf as well.

Thank you for your help and knowledge.

EDIT: To be more direct. I want to build a front end that takes in the data through a form. From there store it in a database. The process I have the question on is how to take that data either from the front end or database and input that in a PDF form(a pre-built standard form that has designated fields and data types typically filled out manually) within the stack I am currently working with. If it's not possible within these languages/stack, what do I need to learn for this function(populate pdf form with inputed data on a webpage) to work.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I recommend all new users visit [ask] and take the [tour] to better understand how to get the most from the site.  In my opinion, the question needs more focus and more specific detail.  It sounds as though you are trying to populate data into a PDF.  Is this to be done in a browser?  Or in a server?  Where is the data coming from?  Because the post doesn't contain some of this context, it is hard for the community to provide helpful information specific to your use case.  While this may be too general for an [mcve], more information would be useful.  Good luck, happy coding!

Comment: One other important point-- is the PDF a PDF _form_, or just a PDF?  It might be helpful to either strip down to just the technical essentials of what you are trying to accomplish, or, alternatively, provide more context of what it is that you are trying to do and why to make sure this isn't an "[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)"...

Comment: @AlexanderNied Thank you for the feedback. Was difficult to form my question with my lack of knowledge and lack of finding anything through my searches to provide code to go off of. I did provide an edit that hopefully clarifies my question.

Comment: Ah perfect didn't even think to use NodeJS for this. Exactly what I needed thank you so much. Should I keep this Question or do I delete it?

Comment: Your call-- if you want you can flag as a duplicate of the question linked in the comment, and then it will got to the review queue and it can be flagged as such.  I already flagged as such so it should probably get noted eventually, and serve as a signpost back to the original question.  That said, if you'd prefer to delete it that is also fine, of course.  Glad that answer has what you need-- good luck on your project!